# only top border of div is displayed

Tags: html, css

I have three div's and try to draw a border on every div.
But it only shows a border at the top of the div`s, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/1/).

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            .mydiv
            {
                position: relative;
                border:1px solid yellow;
            }


            .mydiv_content
            {
                position: absolute;
                border:1px solid red;
            }

            .mydiv_buttons
            {
                position: absolute;
                border:1px solid green;     /* D8D8D8 */
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mydiv">
            <div class="mydiv_content">
                <p> TEST 1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="mydiv_buttons">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="send"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it only shows the border at the top, it would be great if someone can explain this to me. You can find the full code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/1/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/2/

Comment: Why? Because it has no height.

Comment: @Nick, incorrect, the full code is on jsfiddle, i was not allowed to post the whole code. http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/1/

Comment: @EdwardBlack 800% of 0 is 0. it has no height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are setting `height` with `%` relative to the parent `div` which is `position:absolute` and has no `height` defined because your are using on it `height:800%;` that has no affect because of the `position` property.

Just define the `height` of the parent in `px`:

```
.mydiv
{
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid yellow;    /* D8D8D8 */
    width:70%; 
    height:800px; // define the height
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.mydiv` element is not getting proper `Height`

```
.mydiv {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80px; //added
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try change all your class `position:absolute;` into `position:relative;`. Or remove the `position:absolute` in child div.

Try get rid child div height. So won't be huge space in parent div.

Example look at my demo.

My [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6bwy8hg/4/)